# Debug es2015/jsx when transpiled in browser

Tags: babeljs, source-maps

```
<script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>
```

Using the above technique (in browser transpilation with babel), is there a way to get source maps and errors working? Errors that I would expect to appear in the console seem to be swallowed.

Comment: What version of babel? 5 has a much different method of doing this than 6 does.

Comment: 5.8.23 although can change it.